# What is required to create water droplets of a consistent size and shape over a distance of 3 to 10 feet?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

What would I need to do to create water droplets of a consistent size and shape over a distance of 3 to 10 feet?  Are there any special requirements for the nozzle?

Can I use pure water or should I have some kind of additive?

Any special requirements on the valve, etc, that is produced?

Comment: Sorry, this isn't physics. More like DIY or engineering at best.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you only need an appropriate nozzle, called an atomizer. It is basically a very fine nozzle which uses the [Venturi effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venturi_effect) to create a very think cloud of droplets.

There are commercial companies selling specific nozzles by droplet size, distance and distribution (they are typically used in factories).